# All calls are going to voicemail?

Tags: verizon, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I'm still able to make outbound calls without any issue, however inbound calls are going straight to voicemail.  As in instantly.  Not a single ring or even delay.  Straight to voicemail.  Of course I get the voicemails right away and can call back.  Wondering what setting I might have changed to cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A coworker suggested going into airplane mode and then back out.  That corrected the problem.